# How to create an array of arrays as input in ApolloGraphQL

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, graphql-js, apollo-server

How can I create an array of arrays as inputs in [ApolloGraphQL](https://www.apollographql.com/)?

For instance, how should be the Schema for a query like this:

```
{
    Users(Id:1, Filters:[["Id",">", "1"], ["Id","<","3"]]) {
      Id
      Name
    }
}
```

I have tried the following schema but no luck:

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query{
      Users(
        Id: ID,
        Filters: [[String, String, String]]
      )
   }
 `;
```

What I am trying to achieve here is an Input type which is a **List of Lists**, with each of the child lists containing exactly 3 strings. So it can be called like this within the function: `Filters:[["Id",">", "1"], ..]`

Comment: any knowledge about `query variables` and `input types` ? https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#input-types

Comment: Thanks for your link, says nothing about how to create a list of lists as inputs but I appreciate it.

Comment: update question with types you tried to define

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it was easier than I though, would be enough using `[[String]]`:

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query{
      Users(
        Id: ID,
        Filters: [[String]]
      )
   }
 `;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Ander I also tried to achieve something like that, but not luck either. I ended up using list of objects instead:

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query{
      Users(
        Id: ID,
        Filters: [Filter]
      )
  }

  input Filter{
    A: String!
    B: String!
    C: String!
  }
`;
```

It will look like this at the end:

```
{
    Users(Id:1, Filters:[{A:"Id",B:">", C:"1"}, ..]) {
      Id
      Name
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter Its a good alternative, but I find it a bit verbose. I'll keep trying..